# Transpose of matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, transpose

I have a numpy array named `class1`of dimension `50x4`.

I am find the mean of each column of `class1`. `mean1 = np.mean(class1, axis=0)`

`np.mean` returns me `mean1 = [ 5.006  3.428  1.462  0.246]`

When I try to `mean1.T`, it still returns me `[ 5.006  3.428  1.462  0.246]`

What is the correct method to do tranpose?

Basically I want to do `mean1.T * mean1` so that I get a `4x4` matrix

Comment: Did you obtain that with something like `np.mean(class1.T, axis=0)`? If so, your matrix is symmetric, i.e. `A.T==A`

Comment: Have you tried `mean1 = mean1.T` ?

Comment: what do you expect as result?

Comment: Basically i Want to `mean1.T * mean1`, so that i get a 4x4 matrix!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely the simplest and most robust way for many cases is to use [`np.outer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html):

```
>>> mean1 = np.array([ 5.006,  3.428,  1.462,  0.246])
>>> np.outer(mean1, mean1)
array([[ 25.060036,  17.160568,   7.318772,   1.231476],
       [ 17.160568,  11.751184,   5.011736,   0.843288],
       [  7.318772,   5.011736,   2.137444,   0.359652],
       [  1.231476,   0.843288,   0.359652,   0.060516]])
```

As `mean1` is a 1D array `transpose` does nothing as there is nothing to transpose. This is a well intentioned feature of numpy, that sometimes catches people off guard.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
>>> mean1 = mean1[np.newaxis]
>>> mean1 * mean1.T
```

?

Comment: Why not simply `mean1 * mean1[:,None]`?